# Recognize Namaz time in Specific country

Tags: algorithm, flutter, dart, mobile, geolocation

I would create free app for muslims which will notify **pray time ( namaz time).**
I dont know quite a few **how to measure  pray time (Namaz time).**
I saw some **example code**, but these codes were **wrong** for **My Country**  (UZBEKISTAN ).

Please, show or explain how to measure Namaz time for **Uzbekistan** or any country depending on geolocation.

Comment: what do u mean by wrong for your country? there is 2 method standard or hanafi.

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib Algerian Ministry of Religious Affairs and Wakfs,Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı, Turkey, Egyptian General Authority of Survey,Islamic Society of North America,JAKIM,Majlis Ugama Islam Singapura,Muslim World League (Default),Shia Ithna-Ashari, Leva Institute, Qum (Jafri),Sihat/Kemenag,Spiritual Administration of Muslims of Russia,Tunisian Ministry of Religious Affairs,Umm Al-Qura,Union des Organisations Islamiques de France, University Of Islamic Sciences, Karachi ,Custom - Fajar and isha Angle ,Custom - Fajr Angle and Isha time adjustment 
These methods are available.

Comment: I dont know which of them to choose for my country I tried one of them But it was not correct Isha and Fajr.

Comment: i set University Of Islamic Sciences, Karachi. it works for my country.. but how u sure fajr and isha time is wrong for your country?

Comment: https://www.islamicfinder.org/world/uzbekistan/

Comment: visit this site to verify praryer time... here u set calculation method

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib it is official muslim site in UZBEKISTAN 
https://islom.uz/en
where Namaz time is demonstrated. I compared, and found that Fajr and Isha were incorrect

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib is it possible calculate namaz time in offline mode?

Comment: yes you can calculate offline if you have fixed lattitude and longitude... cuase prayer time depends on sun rotation

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib What do u recommend me to do now, after seeing that some namaz times are different from https://islom.uz/en?

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib Hello, Could share your code for namaz time calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

````
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:core';

  void main() {
 double latitude = 41.311081;
 double longitude = 69.240562;
 double timezone = 5;
 // Test Prayer times here
// PrayTime prayers = new PrayTime();
 PrayerTime prayers = new PrayerTime();

 prayers.setTimeFormat(prayers.getTime24());
 prayers.setCalcMethod(prayers.getISNA());
 prayers.setAsrJuristic(prayers.getHanafi());
 prayers.setAdjustHighLats(prayers.getAdjustHighLats());
 List<int>offsets = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // {Fajr,Sunrise,Dhuhr,Asr,Sunset,Maghrib,Isha}
 prayers.tune(offsets);


 List<String> prayerTimes = prayers.getPrayerTimes(DateTime.now(),
 latitude, longitude, timezone);
 List<String> prayerNames = prayers.getTimeNames();

 for (int i = 0; i < prayerTimes.length; i++) {
 print(prayerNames[i] + " - " + prayerTimes[i]);
 }

 }

class PrayerTime {
  // ---------------------- Global Variables --------------------
  int _calcMethod; // caculation method
  int _asrJuristic; // Juristic method for Asr
  int _dhuhrMinutes; // minutes after mid-day for Dhuhr
  int _adjustHighLats; // adjusting method for higher latitudes
  int _timeFormat; // time format
  double _lat; // latitude
  double _lng; // longitude
  double _timeZone; // time-zone
  double _jDate; // Julian date

  // ------------------------------------------------------------
  // Calculation Methods
  int _jafri; // Ithna Ashari
  int _karachi; // University of Islamic Sciences, Karachi
  int _iSNA; // Islamic Society of North America (ISNA)
  int _mWL; // Muslim World League (MWL)
  int _makkah; // Umm al-Qura, Makkah
  int _egypt; // Egyptian General Authority of Survey
  int _custom; // Custom Setting
  int _tehran; // Institute of Geophysics, University of Tehran

  // Juristic Methods
  int _shaffi; // Shafii (standard)
  int _hanafi; // Hanafi

  // Adjusting Methods for Higher Latitudes
  int _none; // No adjustment
  int _midNight; // middle of night
  int _oneSeventh; // 1/7th of night
  int _angleBased; // angle/60th of night

  // Time Formats
  int _time24; // 24-hour format
  int _time12; // 12-hour format
  int _time12Ns; // 12-hour format with no suffix
  int _floating; // floating point number

  // Time Names
  List<String> _timeNames;
  String _invalidTime; // The string used for invalid times

  // --------------------- Technical Settings --------------------
  int _numIterations;

  // ------------------- Calc Method Parameters --------------------
  Map<int, List<double>> _methodParams;

  /*
     * this.methodParams[methodNum] = new Array(fa, ms, mv, is, iv);
     *
     * fa : fajr angle ms : maghrib selector (0 = angle; 1 = minutes after
     * sunset) mv : maghrib parameter value (in angle or minutes) is : isha
     * selector (0 = angle; 1 = minutes after maghrib) iv : isha parameter value
     * (in angle or minutes)
     */

  List<double> _prayerTimesCurrent;
  List<int> _offsets;

  PrayerTime() {
    this.setCalcMethod(0);
    this.setAsrJuristic(0);
    this.setDhuhrMinutes(0);
    this.setAdjustHighLats(1);
    this.setTimeFormat(0);

    // Calculation Methods
    this.setJafari(0); // Ithna Ashari
    this.setKarachi(1); // University of Islamic Sciences, Karachi
    this.setISNA(2); // Islamic Society of North America (ISNA)
    this.setMWL(3); // Muslim World League (MWL)
    this.setMakkah(4); // Umm al-Qura, Makkah
    this.setEgypt(5); // Egyptian General Authority of Survey
    this.setTehran(6); // Institute of Geophysics, University of Tehran
    this.setCustom(7); // Custom Setting

    // Juristic Methods
    this.setShafii(0); // Shafii (standard)
    this.setHanafi(1); // Hanafi

    // Adjusting Methods for Higher Latitudes
    this.setNone(0); // No adjustment
    this.setMidNight(1); // middle of night
    this.setOneSeventh(2); // 1/7th of night
    this.setAngleBased(3); // angle/60th of night

    // Time Formats
    this.setTime24(0); // 24-hour format
    this.setTime12(1); // 12-hour format
    this.setTime12NS(2); // 12-hour format with no suffix
    this.setFloating(3); // floating point number

    // Time Names
    _timeNames = new List<String>();
    _timeNames.add("Fajr");
    _timeNames.add("Sunrise");
    _timeNames.add("Dhuhr");
    _timeNames.add("Asr");
    _timeNames.add("Sunset");
    _timeNames.add("Maghrib");
    _timeNames.add("Isha");

    _invalidTime = "-----"; // The string used for invalid times

    // --------------------- Technical Settings --------------------

    this.setNumIterations(1); // number of iterations needed to compute
    // times

    // ------------------- Calc Method Parameters --------------------

    // Tuning offsets {fajr, sunrise, dhuhr, asr, sunset, maghrib, isha}
    _offsets = new List<int>(7);
    _offsets[0] = 0;
    _offsets[1] = 0;
    _offsets[2] = 0;
    _offsets[3] = 0;
    _offsets[4] = 0;
    _offsets[5] = 0;
    _offsets[6] = 0;

    /*
         *
         * fa : fajr angle ms : maghrib selector (0 = angle; 1 = minutes after
         * sunset) mv : maghrib parameter value (in angle or minutes) is : isha
         * selector (0 = angle; 1 = minutes after maghrib) iv : isha parameter
         * value (in angle or minutes)
         */
    _methodParams = new HashMap<int, List<double>>();

    // Jafari
    List<double> _jValues = [16, 0, 4, 0, 14];
    _methodParams[this.getJafari()] = _jValues;

    // Karachi
    List<double> _kValues = [18, 1, 0, 0, 18];
    _methodParams[this.getKarachi()] = _kValues;

    // ISNA
    List<double> _iValues = [15, 1, 0, 0, 15];
    _methodParams[this.getISNA()] = _iValues;

    // MWL
    List<double> _mwValues = [18, 1, 0, 0, 17];
    _methodParams[this.getMWL()] = _mwValues;

    // Makkah
    List<double> _mkValues = [18.5, 1, 0, 1, 90];
    _methodParams[this.getMakkah()] = _mkValues;

    // Egypt
    List<double> _eValues = [19.5, 1, 0, 0, 17.5];
    _methodParams[this.getEgypt()] = _eValues;

    // Tehran
    List<double> _tValues = [17.7, 0, 4.5, 0, 14];
    _methodParams[this.getTehran()] = _tValues;

    // Custom
    List<double> _cValues = [18, 1, 0, 0, 17];
    _methodParams[this.getCustom()] = _cValues;
  }

  // ---------------------- Trigonometric Functions -----------------------
  // range reduce angle in degrees.

  double _fixAngle(double a) {
    a = a - (360 * ((a / 360.0).floor()));
    a = a < 0 ? (a + 360) : a;

    return a;
  }

  //range reduce hours to 0..23

  double _fixHour(double a) {
    a = a - 24.0 * (a / 24.0).floor();
    a = a < 0 ? (a + 24) : a;
    return a;
  }

  // radian to degree
  double _radiansToDegrees(double alpha) {
    return ((alpha * 180.0) / math.pi);
  }

  // deree to radian
  double _degreesToRadians(double alpha) {
    return ((alpha * math.pi) / 180.0);
  }

  // degree sin
  double _dsin(double d) {
    return (math.sin(_degreesToRadians(d)));
  }

  // degree cos
  double _dcos(double d) {
    return (math.cos(_degreesToRadians(d)));
  }

  // degree tan
  double _dtan(double d) {
    return (math.tan(_degreesToRadians(d)));
  }

  // degree arcsin
  double _darcsin(double x) {
    double val = math.asin(x);
    return _radiansToDegrees(val);
  }

  // degree arccos
  double darccos(double x) {
    double val = math.acos(x);
    return _radiansToDegrees(val);
  }

  // degree arctan
  double _darctan(double x) {
    double val = math.atan(x);
    return _radiansToDegrees(val);
  }

  // degree arctan2
  double _darctan2(double y, double x) {
    double val = math.atan2(y, x);
    return _radiansToDegrees(val);
  }

  // degree arccot
  double darccot(double x) {
    double val = math.atan2(1.0, x);
    return _radiansToDegrees(val);
  }

  // ---------------------- Time-Zone Functions -----------------------
  // compute local time-zone for a specific date
/*   getTimeZone1() {
    TimeZone timez = TimeZone.;
    double hoursDiff = (timez.getRawOffset() / 1000.0) / 3600;
    return hoursDiff;
  }
  // compute base time-zone of the system
   getBaseTimeZone() {
    TimeZone timez = TimeZone.getDefault();
    double hoursDiff = (timez.getRawOffset() / 1000.0) / 3600;
    return hoursDiff;
  }
  // detect daylight saving in a given date
   detectDaylightSaving() {
    TimeZone timez = TimeZone.UTC;
    double hoursDiff = timez.getDSTSavings();
    return hoursDiff;
  }*/

  // ---------------------- Julian Date Functions -----------------------
  // calculate julian date from a calendar date
  julianDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    if (month <= 2) {
      year -= 1;
      month += 12;
    }
    double A = (year / 100.0).floorToDouble();

    double B = 2 - A + (A / 4.0).floor();

    double JD = (365.25 * (year + 4716)).floor() +
        (30.6001 * (month + 1)).floor() +
        day +
        B -
        1524.5;

    return JD;
  }

  /*// convert a calendar date to julian date (second method)
   calcJD(int year, int month, int day) {
    double J1970 = 2440588.0;
    Date date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    double ms = date.getTime(); // # of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1,
    // 1970
    double days = (ms / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)).floorToDouble();
    return J1970 + days - 0.5;
  }*/

  //
  // ---------------------- Calculation Functions -----------------------

  // ---------------------- Calculation Functions -----------------------
  // References:
  // http://www.ummah.net/astronomy/saltime
  // http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/SunApprox.html
  // compute declination angle of sun and equation of time
  List<double> sunPosition(double jd) {
    double D = jd - 2451545;
    double g = _fixAngle(357.529 + 0.98560028 * D);
    double q = _fixAngle(280.459 + 0.98564736 * D);
    double L = _fixAngle(q + (1.915 * _dsin(g)) + (0.020 * _dsin(2 * g)));

    // double R = 1.00014 - 0.01671 * [self dcos:g] - 0.00014 * [self dcos:
    // (2*g)];
    double e = 23.439 - (0.00000036 * D);
    double d = _darcsin(_dsin(e) * _dsin(L));
    double RA = (_darctan2((_dcos(e) * _dsin(L)), (_dcos(L)))) / 15.0;
    RA = _fixHour(RA);
    double EqT = q / 15.0 - RA;
    List<double> sPosition = new List(2);
    sPosition[0] = d;
    sPosition[1] = EqT;

    return sPosition;
  }

  // compute equation of time

  double equationOfTime(double jd) {
    double eq = sunPosition(jd)[1];
    return eq;
  }

  // compute declination angle of sun
  double sunDeclination(double jd) {
    double d = sunPosition(jd)[0];
    return d;
  }

  // compute mid-day (Dhuhr, Zawal) time
  double computeMidDay(double t) {
    double T = equationOfTime(this.getJDate() + t);
    double Z = _fixHour(12 - T);
    return Z;
  }

  // compute time for a given angle G
  double computeTime(double G, double t) {
    double D = sunDeclination(this.getJDate() + t);
    double Z = computeMidDay(t);
    double Beg = -_dsin(G) - _dsin(D) * _dsin(this.getLat());
    double Mid = _dcos(D) * _dcos(this.getLat());
    double V = darccos(Beg / Mid) / 15.0;

    return Z + (G > 90 ? -V : V);
  }

  // compute the time of Asr
  // Shafii: step=1, Hanafi: step=2
  double computeAsr(double step, double t) {
    double D = sunDeclination(this.getJDate() + t);
    double G = -darccot(step + _dtan((this.getLat() - D).abs()));
    return computeTime(G, t);
  }

  // ---------------------- Misc Functions -----------------------
  // compute the difference between two times
  double timeDiff(double time1, double time2) {
    return _fixHour(time2 - time1);
  }

  // -------------------- Interface Functions --------------------
  // return prayer times for a given date
  List<String> getDatePrayerTimes(int year, int month, int day, double latitude,
      double longitude, double tZone) {
    this.setLat(latitude);
    this.setLng(longitude);
    this.setTimeZone(tZone);
    this.setJDate(julianDate(year, month, day));
    double lonDiff = longitude / (15.0 * 24.0);
    this.setJDate(this.getJDate() - lonDiff);
    return computeDayTimes();
  }

  // return prayer times for a given date
  List<String> getPrayerTimes(
      DateTime date, double latitude, double longitude, double tZone) {
    int year = date.year;
    int month = date.month;
    int day = date.day;

    return getDatePrayerTimes(year, month, day, latitude, longitude, tZone);
  }

  // set custom values for calculation parameters
  void setCustomParams(List<double> params) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (params[i] == null) {
        params[i] = _methodParams[this._calcMethod][i];
        _methodParams[this.getCustom()] = params;
      } else {
        _methodParams[this.getCustom()][i] = params[i];
      }
    }
    this.setCalcMethod(this.getCustom());
  }

  // set the angle for calculating Fajr
  void setFajrAngle(double angle) {
    List<double> params = [angle, -1, -1, -1, -1];
    setCustomParams(params);
  }

  // set the angle for calculating Maghrib
  void setMaghribAngle(double angle) {
    List<double> params = [-1, 0, angle, -1, -1];
    setCustomParams(params);
  }

  // set the angle for calculating Isha
  void setIshaAngle(double angle) {
    List<double> params = [-1, -1, -1, 0, angle];
    setCustomParams(params);
  }

  // set the minutes after Sunset for calculating Maghrib
  void setMaghribMinutes(double minutes) {
    List<double> params = [-1, 1, minutes, -1, -1];
    setCustomParams(params);
  }

  // set the minutes after Maghrib for calculating Isha
  void setIshaMinutes(double minutes) {
    List<double> params = [-1, -1, -1, 1, minutes];
    setCustomParams(params);
  }

  // convert double hours to 24h format
  String floatToTime24(double time) {
    String result;

    if (time == double.nan) {
      return _invalidTime;
    }

    time = _fixHour(time + 0.5 / 60.0); // add 0.5 minutes to round
    int hours = time.floor();
    double minutes = ((time - hours) * 60.0).floorToDouble();

    if ((hours >= 0 && hours <= 9) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 9)) {
      result = "0" + hours.toString() + ":0" + (minutes).round().toString();
    } else if ((hours >= 0 && hours <= 9)) {
      result = "0" + hours.toString() + ":" + (minutes).round().toString();
    } else if ((minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 9)) {
      result = hours.toString() + ":0" + (minutes).round().toString();
    } else {
      result = hours.toString() + ":" + (minutes).round().toString();
    }
    return result;
  }

  // convert double hours to 12h format
  String floatToTime12(double time, bool noSuffix) {
    if (time == double.nan) {
      return _invalidTime;
    }

    time = _fixHour(time + 0.5 / 60); // add 0.5 minutes to round
    int hours = (time).floor();
    double minutes = ((time - hours) * 60).floorToDouble();
    String suffix, result;
    if (hours >= 12) {
      suffix = "PM";
    } else {
      suffix = "AM";
    }
    hours = ((((hours + 12) - 1) % (12)) + 1);
    /*hours = (hours + 12) - 1;
        int hrs = (int) hours % 12;
        hrs += 1;*/
    if (noSuffix == false) {
      if ((hours >= 0 && hours <= 9) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 9)) {
        result = "0" +
            hours.toString() +
            ":0" +
            (minutes).round().toString() +
            " " +
            suffix;
      } else if ((hours >= 0 && hours <= 9)) {
        result = "0" +
            hours.toString() +
            ":" +
            (minutes).round().toString() +
            " " +
            suffix;
      } else if ((minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 9)) {
        result = hours.toString() +
            ":0" +
            (minutes).round().toString() +
            " " +
            suffix;
      } else {
        result = hours.toString() +
            ":" +
            (minutes).round().toString() +
            " " +
            suffix;
      }
    } else {
      if ((hours >= 0 && hours <= 9) && (minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 9)) {
        result = "0" + hours.toString() + ":0" + (minutes).round().toString();
      } else if ((hours >= 0 && hours <= 9)) {
        result = "0" + hours.toString() + ":" + (minutes).round().toString();
      } else if ((minutes >= 0 && minutes <= 9)) {
        result = hours.toString() + ":0" + (minutes).round().toString();
      } else {
        result = hours.toString() + ":" + (minutes).round().toString();
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  // convert double hours to 12h format with no suffix
  String floatToTime12NS(double time) {
    return floatToTime12(time, true);
  }

  // ---------------------- Compute Prayer Times -----------------------
  // compute prayer times at given julian date
  List<double> computeTimes(List<double> times) {
    List<double> t = dayPortion(times);

    double Fajr =
    this.computeTime(180 - _methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][0], t[0]);

    double Sunrise = this.computeTime(180 - 0.833, t[1]);

    double Dhuhr = this.computeMidDay(t[2]);
    double Asr = this.computeAsr((1 + this.getAsrJuristic()).toDouble(), t[3]);
    double Sunset = this.computeTime(0.833, t[4]);

    double Maghrib =
    this.computeTime(_methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][2], t[5]);
    double Isha =
    this.computeTime(_methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][4], t[6]);

    List<double> CTimes = [Fajr, Sunrise, Dhuhr, Asr, Sunset, Maghrib, Isha];

    return CTimes;
  }

  // compute prayer times at given julian date
  List<String> computeDayTimes() {
    List<double> times = [5, 6, 12, 13, 18, 18, 18]; // default times

    for (int i = 1; i <= this.getNumIterations(); i++) {
      times = computeTimes(times);
    }

    times = adjustTimes(times);
    times = tuneTimes(times);

    return adjustTimesFormat(times);
  }

  // adjust times in a prayer time array
  List<double> adjustTimes(List<double> times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      times[i] += this.getTimeZone() - this.getLng() / 15;
    }

    times[2] += this.getDhuhrMinutes() / 60; // Dhuhr

    if (_methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][1] == 1) {
      times[5] = times[4] + _methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][2] / 60;
    }
    if (_methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][3] == 1) {
      times[6] = times[5] + _methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][4] / 60;
    }

    if (this.getAdjustHighLats() != this.getNone()) {
      times = adjustHighLatTimes(times);
    }

    return times;
  }

  // convert times array to given time format
  List<String> adjustTimesFormat(List<double> times) {
    List<String> result = new List<String>();
    if (this.getTimeFormat() == this.getFloating()) {
      for (double time in times) {
        result.add(time.toString());
      }
      return result;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      if (this.getTimeFormat() == this.getTime12()) {
        result.add(floatToTime12(times[i], false));
      } else if (this.getTimeFormat() == this.getTime12NS()) {
        result.add(floatToTime12(times[i], true));
      } else {
        result.add(floatToTime24(times[i]));
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  // adjust Fajr, Isha and Maghrib for locations in higher latitudes
  List<double> adjustHighLatTimes(List<double> times) {
    double nightTime = timeDiff(times[4], times[1]); // sunset to sunrise

    // Adjust Fajr
    double FajrDiff =
        nightPortion(_methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][0]) * nightTime;

    if (times[0] == double.nan || timeDiff(times[0], times[1]) > FajrDiff) {
      times[0] = times[1] - FajrDiff;
    }

    // Adjust Isha
    double IshaAngle = (_methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][3] == 0)
        ? _methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][4]
        : 18;
    double IshaDiff = this.nightPortion(IshaAngle) * nightTime;

    if (times[6] == double.nan ||
        this.timeDiff(times[4], times[6]) > IshaDiff) {
      times[6] = times[4] + IshaDiff;
    }

    // Adjust Maghrib
    double MaghribAngle = (_methodParams[this.getCalcMethod()][1] == 0)
        ? _methodParams[(this.getCalcMethod())][2]
        : 4;
    double MaghribDiff = nightPortion(MaghribAngle) * nightTime;

    if (times[5] == double.nan ||
        this.timeDiff(times[4], times[5]) > MaghribDiff) {
      times[5] = times[4] + MaghribDiff;
    }

    return times;
  }

  // the night portion used for adjusting times in higher latitudes
  double nightPortion(double angle) {
    double calc = 0;

    if (_adjustHighLats == _angleBased)
      calc = (angle) / 60.0;
    else if (_adjustHighLats == _midNight)
      calc = 0.5;
    else if (_adjustHighLats == _oneSeventh) calc = 0.14286;

    return calc;
  }

  // convert hours to day portions
  List<double> dayPortion(List<double> times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      times[i] /= 24;
    }
    return times;
  }

  // Tune timings for adjustments
  // Set time offsets
  void tune(List<int> offsetTimes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < offsetTimes.length; i++) {
      // offsetTimes length
      // should be 7 in order
      // of Fajr, Sunrise,
      // Dhuhr, Asr, Sunset,
      // Maghrib, Isha
      this._offsets[i] = offsetTimes[i];
    }
  }

  List<double> tuneTimes(List<double> times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      times[i] = times[i] + this._offsets[i] / 60.0;
    }
    return times;
  }

  int getCalcMethod() {
    return _calcMethod;
  }

  void setCalcMethod(int calcMethod) {
    _calcMethod = calcMethod;
  }

  int getAsrJuristic() {
    return _asrJuristic;
  }

  void setAsrJuristic(int asrJuristic) {
    _asrJuristic = asrJuristic;
  }

  int getDhuhrMinutes() {
    return _dhuhrMinutes;
  }

  void setDhuhrMinutes(int dhuhrMinutes) {
    _dhuhrMinutes = dhuhrMinutes;
  }

  int getAdjustHighLats() {
    return _adjustHighLats;
  }

  void setAdjustHighLats(int adjustHighLats) {
    _adjustHighLats = adjustHighLats;
  }

  int getTimeFormat() {
    return _timeFormat;
  }

  setTimeFormat(int timeFormat) {
    _timeFormat = timeFormat;
  }

  double getLat() {
    return _lat;
  }

  void setLat(double lat) {
    _lat = lat;
  }

  double getLng() {
    return _lng;
  }

  void setLng(double lng) {
    _lng = lng;
  }

  double getTimeZone() {
    return _timeZone;
  }

  void setTimeZone(double timeZone) {
    _timeZone = timeZone;
  }

  double getJDate() {
    return _jDate;
  }

  void setJDate(double jDate) {
    _jDate = jDate;
  }

  int getJafari() {
    return _jafri;
  }

  void setJafari(int jafari) {
    _jafri = jafari;
  }

  int getKarachi() {
    return _karachi;
  }

  void setKarachi(int karachi) {
    _karachi = karachi;
  }

  int getISNA() {
    return _iSNA;
  }

  void setISNA(int iSNA) {
    _iSNA = iSNA;
  }

  int getMWL() {
    return _mWL;
  }

  void setMWL(int mWL) {
    _mWL = mWL;
  }

  int getMakkah() {
    return _makkah;
  }

  void setMakkah(int makkah) {
    _makkah = makkah;
  }

  int getEgypt() {
    return _egypt;
  }

  void setEgypt(int egypt) {
    _egypt = egypt;
  }

  int getCustom() {
    return _custom;
  }

  void setCustom(int custom) {
    _custom = custom;
  }

  int getTehran() {
    return _tehran;
  }

  void setTehran(int tehran) {
    _tehran = tehran;
  }

  int getShafii() {
    return _shaffi;
  }

  void setShafii(int shafii) {
    _shaffi = shafii;
  }

  int getHanafi() {
    return _hanafi;
  }

  void setHanafi(int hanafi) {
    _hanafi = hanafi;
  }

  int getNone() {
    return _none;
  }

  void setNone(int none) {
    _none = none;
  }

  int getMidNight() {
    return _midNight;
  }

  void setMidNight(int midNight) {
    _midNight = midNight;
  }

  int getOneSeventh() {
    return _oneSeventh;
  }

  void setOneSeventh(int oneSeventh) {
    _oneSeventh = oneSeventh;
  }

  int getAngleBased() {
    return _angleBased;
  }

  void setAngleBased(int angleBased) {
    _angleBased = angleBased;
  }

  int getTime24() {
    return _time24;
  }

  void setTime24(int time24) {
    _time24 = time24;
  }

  int getTime12() {
    return _time12;
  }

  void setTime12(int time12) {
    _time12 = time12;
  }

  int getTime12NS() {
    return _time12Ns;
  }

  void setTime12NS(int time12ns) {
    _time12Ns = time12ns;
  }

  int getFloating() {
    return _floating;
  }

  void setFloating(int floating) {
    _floating = floating;
  }

  int getNumIterations() {
    return _numIterations;
  }

  void setNumIterations(int numIterations) {
    _numIterations = numIterations;
  }

  List<String> getTimeNames() {
    return _timeNames;
  }
}```
````

Comment: there is many open source library to calculate praryer time. you can also chek those.

Comment: how can I retrieve the tZone variable